# Access local variable inside function and check ng-click in jasmine test with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Hello I have following code

```
myApp.controller('myctrl',function($scope,myservice){
  //where testClickEvent is ng-click from partials
 $scope.testClickEvent=function(args){      
   var setArg1=args[0];
   var params = {"myarg1":setArg1}      
  //rest call         
   myservice.testClickEvent(params).success(function(data){
      if(data.res==true)
      {
          $scope.somevariable="success";
      }

  }).error(function(error){    
      $scope.somevariable="failure";
    });
  }
});
```

I wanted to test it using jasmine that is

1. testing `ng-click` event happened in partial ??
2. how do i test `$scope.somevariable` and `setArg1` has got proper value

   here i have used

   ```
   spyOn(scope,testClickEvent); 
   scope.testClickEvent(args);
   expect(scope.testClickEvent).toHaveBeenCalledWith(args);
   spyOn(myservice,testClickEvent); 
   myservice.testClickEvent(params);
   expect(myservice.testClickEvent).toHaveBeenCalledWith(params);
   ```

works but how to access result and async call back result????

Thanks in advance ! Your Help appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

You would need to mock out the call using `$httpBackend`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

The example from the angular page has the following 2 lines:

`$httpBackend.when('GET', '/auth.py').respond({userId: 'userX'}, {'A-Token': 'xxx'});` `$httpBackend.expectPOST('/add-msg.py', 'message content').respond(201, '');`

The first one mocks out the response and responds with whatever object is specified
The second one expects the server to be called with a specified object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! but that thing i am doing already in serviceSpec individually for service. I accept that without doing $httpBackend i wont be able to get result.but is there any work around just to test async call in controller and result value  Also any idea to test ng-click event.